# Using UNION inside of NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, union, notin

I'm trying to make query using a `NOT IN` condition. If I use a subquery I got no problem, but when I try to use `UNION` to join results from two tables, I got an error.

This is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN( 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) AS id
        FROM users_table_1
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT(user_id) AS id
        FROM users_table_2
    )   
)
```

Is there a way to get what I want using subqueries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's a syntax issue in your code. Did you try to put `UNION` *inside* the subquery?

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN( 
        SELECT user_id AS id
        FROM users_table_1
        UNION
        SELECT user_id
        FROM users_table_2 
)
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword is redundant (see @ypercube's comment).

Comment: Yes, it was that. I thought I could use parentheses any way I want to group my queries. New thing learned :).

Comment: @Yasir, which version does this error (from  the second occurrence of `AS id`) occur into? I can't reproduce it in SQLFiddle. Plus, the two `DISTINCT` are redundant as `UNION` has as default `UNION DISTINCT` and will remove all duplicates anyway.

Comment: @ypercube I think I confused the column alias name appearing more than once with the `ORDER BY` clause specified in any query other than the last one in the set operator, i. e. this query gives an error `select 'foo' from dual order by 1 union select 'bar' from dual`, while this doesn't `select 'foo' from dual union select 'bar' from dual order by 1`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@yasir Actually, this is not a real syntax problem (the same syntax is accepted by other SQL databases), but rather a limitation in MySQL query parser, [implemented using the bison parser generator](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/sql_yacc.yy).

The error stems from the parser's need to decide between two possible parse trees, since both SELECT subqueries and sub-expressions may be enclosed in parentheses. Therefore a minimal solution here would be to remove the parens *only* from the first subquery, i.e.:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN( 
    SELECT user_id AS id
    FROM users_table_1
    UNION
    (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM users_table_2
    )
)
```

This way you "help" mysql disambiguate between the two possible parse trees. In bison lingo, that would avoid the shift/reduce conflict.